# Need to calculate total amount of time take for a ticket in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a log table for ticket history in SQL Server 2008. here I have  datetime and Status filed. I have to calculate total time i spent on this ticket. 
Here I have to calculate total time from accepted to closed status and I have to exclude pending vender status

`time(datediff(minute,'2015-06-19 16:03:13.000', '2015-06-22 06:32:31.000')+datediff(minute,'2015-06-22 11:15:15.000', '2015-06-23 10:15:15.000'))`.

And I have more than 2 statuses

Example:

```
'ticket_number    Date & Time             Problem Status
  16676        2015-06-19 15:50:14.000     Open
  16676        2015-06-19 15:50:14.000     Accepted
  16676        2015-06-19 15:50:44.000     Work in progress
  16676        2015-06-19 16:03:13.000     Pending Vendor
  16676        2015-06-22 06:32:31.000     Work in progress
  16676        2015-06-22 11:15:15.000     Pending Vendor
  16676        2015-06-23 10:15:15.000     Work in progress
  16676        2015-06-23 10:15:15.000     Closed'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` with `GROUP BY` like this.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b80ce8/2)

**Query**

```
SELECT t1.ticket_number,SUM(DATEDIFF(second,DateTime,CloseTime)) as TotalSeconds
FROM tickets t1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 DateTime as CloseTime FROM tickets t2 WHERE t1.ticket_number = t2.ticket_number and t2.id > t1.id ORDER BY t2.DateTime) as t2
WHERE t1.ProblemStatus <> 'Pending Vendor'
GROUP BY t1.ticket_number
```

**Output**

```
| ticket_number | TotalSeconds |
|---------------|--------------|
|         16676 |        17743 |
```